# Postscript: Need help understanding legacy code

Tags: postscript

I am hoping a Postscript guru can help me understand this code fragment:

```
1 %%BeginFeature: InputSlot Tray2
2  1 dict dup /MediaPosition null put setpagedevice
3  userdict /lms
4  currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get 1 known { 1 }{ 0 }ifelse put
5  currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get lms get setpagedevice
```

In very broad strokes I am pretty sure it is trying to figure out whether the printer has a Tray 2 and if it does to use it, otherwise use Tray 1 - except it doesn't work!

It used to with Ricoh MFPs (copier/printer) but doesn't with Sharp MFPs.

I have tried changing line 4 to

```
currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get 1 known { 1 }{ 1 }ifelse put
```

but that didn't work either.

What finally worked was to change line 2 to

```
1 dict dup /MediaPosition 1 put setpagedevice
```

which just assumes Tray 2 exists but I am ok with that for now; but now I'd really like to understand what line 3 - 5 actually do.

I **think** line 3 puts a *dict* called `lms` on the stack and puts either a 1 or a 0 on the stack (line 4) depending on what /InputAttributes has(? this is where I'm a bit fuzzy). No idea what line 5 is doing.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am hoping a Postscript guru can help me understand this code
>   fragment

```
1 dict dup /MediaPosition null put setpagedevice
```

Create a dictionary that contains one item `{MediaPosition: null}`; merge the content of this little dictionary with the pagedevice dictionary.

```
userdict /lms currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get 1 known { 1 }{ 0 }ifelse put
```

Get the dictionary stored under the `InputAttributes` key from the current pagedevice dictionary.  If there's a key called `1` in the `InputAttributes` dictionary (the keys of the `InputAttributes` dictionary are all numbers, under which are stored dictionaries as values), then set the value of `lms` in the user dictionary to `1` otherwise `0`.  (I.e. save that 0 or 1 key.)

```
currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get lms get setpagedevice
```

From the current pagedevice dictionary, get the `InputAttributes` dictionary once again, and lookup the numeric key that we stored in the `lms` variable (now a symbol in userdict).  Whichever dictionary you get back (from key `0` or key `1`), merge that dictionary into the pagedevice dictionary.

I.e. if tray definition 1 exists, select it, otherwise default to tray definition 0.  The `lms` symbol may have no inherent meaning here, it could be just a temporary.  However, if that's the case, then we could replace those two lines with something like:

```
currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get dup 1 known { 1 }{ 0 }ifelse get setpagedevice
```

So either they wanted `lms` to continue to exist beyond this use, or they just weren't all that comfortable with PostScript!

Since fragments of the above code turn up in Lexmark PPD files, I'm guessing it stands for 'LexMark Systems', or some such, and that this script may have originated from a Lexmark printer before the Ricoh.

There may be a standard way to select tray devices that you might discover by studying PPD files.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @cdlane. One thing I still don't understand, though, is why setting `{MediaPosition: null}` since, in the end, this is how the tray is actually selected - at least on a Sharp. I suppose I'll have to see what it does for a Lexmark.